# Text-based Tetris game - follow-up

Tags: c++, c++11, game, tetris

Previous question:

[Text-based Tetris game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74293/text-based-tetris-game)

I don't have a Linux terminal to be sure whether or not I have implemented the Linux version correctly, but hopefully it's OK.

Summary of improvements:

- More OOP
- Improved the names of the classes and their functions and I hope they're OK now
- More portable, isolated platform-specific code
- Eliminated "magic numbers"

I would like to know if there is anything I should take care of before processing the code.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

#ifdef __linux__ 
/*****************************************************************************
kbhit() and getch() for Linux/UNIX
Chris Giese <geezer@execpc.com> http://my.execpc.com/~geezer
Release date: ?
This code is public domain (no copyright).
You can do whatever you want with it.
****************************************************************************/
#include <sys/time.h> /* struct timeval, select() */
/* ICANON, ECHO, TCSANOW, struct termios */
#include <termios.h> /* tcgetattr(), tcsetattr() */
#include <stdlib.h> /* atexit(), exit() */
#include <unistd.h> /* read() */
#include <stdio.h> /* printf() */

static struct termios g_old_kbd_mode;
/*****************************************************************************
*****************************************************************************/
static void cooked(void)
{
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &g_old_kbd_mode);
}
/*****************************************************************************
*****************************************************************************/
static void raw(void)
{
    static char init;
    /**/
    struct termios new_kbd_mode;

    if (init)
        return;
    /* put keyboard (stdin, actually) in raw, unbuffered mode */
    tcgetattr(0, &g_old_kbd_mode);
    memcpy(&new_kbd_mode, &g_old_kbd_mode, sizeof(struct termios));
    new_kbd_mode.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
    new_kbd_mode.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    new_kbd_mode.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_kbd_mode);
    /* when we exit, go back to normal, "cooked" mode */
    atexit(cooked);

    init = 1;
}
/*****************************************************************************
*****************************************************************************/
static int _kbhit(void)
{
    struct timeval timeout;
    fd_set read_handles;
    int status;

    raw();
    /* check stdin (fd 0) for activity */
    FD_ZERO(&read_handles);
    FD_SET(0, &read_handles);
    timeout.tv_sec = timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    status = select(0 + 1, &read_handles, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    if (status < 0)
    {
        printf("select() failed in kbhit()\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return status;
}
/*****************************************************************************
*****************************************************************************/
static int _getch(void)
{
    unsigned char temp;

    raw();
    /* stdin = fd 0 */
    if (read(0, &temp, 1) != 1)
        return 0;
    return temp;
}
struct COORD { short X; short Y; };
bool gotoxy(unsigned short x = 1, unsigned short y = 1) {
    if ((x == 0) || (y == 0))
        return false;
    std::cout << "\x1B[" << y << ";" << x << "H";
}

void clearScreen(bool moveToStart = true) {
    std::cout << "\x1B[2J";
    if (moveToStart)
        gotoxy(1, 1);
}
inline
void print(std::string& str, COORD& coord)
{
    gotoxy(coord.X, coord.Y);
    std::cout << str << std::flush;;
}
inline
void print(TCHAR* str, COORD& coord){
    gotoxy(coord.X, coord.Y);
    std::cout << str << std::flush;;
}
inline
void print(TCHAR& c, COORD& coord){
    gotoxy(coord.X, coord.Y);
    std::cout << c << std::flush;
}
#elif _WIN32
#include <conio.h> /* kbhit(), getch() */
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
void clearScreen()
{
    HANDLE                     hStdOut;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    DWORD                      count;
    DWORD                      cellCount;
    COORD                      homeCoords = { 0, 0 };

    hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if (hStdOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return;

    if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdOut, &csbi)) return;
    cellCount = csbi.dwSize.X *csbi.dwSize.Y;

    if (!FillConsoleOutputCharacter(
        hStdOut,
        (TCHAR) ' ',
        cellCount,
        homeCoords,
        &count
        )) return;

    if (!FillConsoleOutputAttribute(
        hStdOut,
        csbi.wAttributes,
        cellCount,
        homeCoords,
        &count
        )) return;

    /* Move the cursor home */
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOut, homeCoords);
}
void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = x;
    coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}
static CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
COORD getXY()
{

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
    COORD position;
    position.X = csbi.dwCursorPosition.X;
    position.Y = csbi.dwCursorPosition.Y;
    return position;
}
static DWORD cCharsWritten = 0;
inline
void print(std::string& str, COORD& coord)
{
    WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), str.c_str(), str.length(), coord, &cCharsWritten);
}
inline
void print(TCHAR* str, COORD& coord)
{
    WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), str, _tcslen(str), coord, &cCharsWritten);
}
inline
void print(TCHAR& c, COORD& coord)
{
    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), c, 1, coord, &cCharsWritten);
}
#else
#error "OS not supported!"
#endif

static std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> block_list =
{
    {
        { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 0 }
    },
    {
        { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 0 }
    },
    {
        { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
    },
    {
        { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
    },
    {
        { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
    },
    {
        { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
    },
    {
        { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 1, 0 }
    }
};

struct NonCopyable
{
    NonCopyable() = default;
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable &) = delete;
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable &&) = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator = (const NonCopyable&) = delete;
};


struct Random : public NonCopyable
{
    Random(int min, int max)
        : mUniformDistribution(min, max)
    {}

    int operator()()
    {
        return mUniformDistribution(mEngine);
    }

    std::default_random_engine mEngine{ std::random_device()() };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> mUniformDistribution;
};

struct Block : public NonCopyable
{
    static const int ROTATIONS_IN_CIRCLE = 4;
    int rotation_count = 0;

    COORD coord;

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> block;

    Block()
    {
        block.resize(4, std::vector<int>(4, 0));
        coord.X = 0;
        coord.Y = 0;
    }

    void rotate()
    {
        ++rotation_count;

        while (rotation_count > ROTATIONS_IN_CIRCLE)
        {
            rotation_count -= ROTATIONS_IN_CIRCLE;
        }
    }

    int& getDim(int row, int column)
    {
        switch (rotation_count % ROTATIONS_IN_CIRCLE)
        {
        default:
            return block[row][column];
        case 1:
            return block[block.size() - column - 1][row];
        case 2:
            return block[block.size() - row - 1][block.size() - column - 1];
        case 3:
            return block[column][block.size() - row - 1];
        }
    }

    size_t size()
    {
        return block.size();
    }

};

struct Board : public NonCopyable
{
    Board()
    {
        field.resize(22, std::vector<int>(13, 0));
        coord.X = 0;
        coord.Y = 0;
    }

    COORD coord;

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> field;

    int& getDim(int row, int column)
    {
        return field[row][column];
    }

    size_t size() const
    {
        return field.size();
    }
    size_t rowSize() const
    {
        return field[0].size();
    }
};

struct Collidable : public NonCopyable
{
    Collidable()
    {
        stage.resize(22, std::vector<int>(13, 0));
        coord.X = 0;
        coord.Y = 0;
    }

    COORD coord;

    int& getDim(int row, int column)
    {
        return stage[row][column];
    }

    size_t size() const
    {
        return stage.size();
    }
    size_t rowSize() const
    {
        return stage[0].size();
    }
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> stage;
};

class Tetris : public NonCopyable
{
public:
    Tetris() 
        : board(), block(), stage()
    {};
    bool makeBlocks();
    void initField();
    void moveBlock(int, int);
    void collidable();
    bool isCollide(int, int);
    void userInput();
    bool rotateBlock();
    void spawnBlock();
    virtual void display(){};
    virtual void GameOverScreen() {};

protected:
    int y = 0;
    int x = 4;
    bool gameOver = false;
    Board board;
    Block block;
    Collidable stage;
    Random getRandom{ 0, 6 };
};

void Tetris::initField()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= board.size() - 2; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j <= board.rowSize() - 2; ++j)
        {
            if ((j == 0) || (j == 11) || (i == 20))
            {
                board.getDim(i, j) = stage.getDim(i, j) = 9;
            }
            else
            {
                board.getDim(i, j) = stage.getDim(i, j) = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    makeBlocks();

    display();
}

bool Tetris::makeBlocks()
{
    x = 4;
    y = 0;

    int blockType = getRandom();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < block.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < block.size(); ++j)
        {
            block.getDim(i, j) = 0;
            block.getDim(i, j) = block_list[blockType][i][j];
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < block.size(); i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < block.size(); j++)
        {
            board.getDim(i, j + block.size()) = stage.getDim(i, j + block.size()) + block.getDim(i, j);

            if (board.getDim(i, j + block.size()) > 1)
            {
                gameOver = true;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void Tetris::moveBlock(int x2, int y2)
{

    //Remove block
    for (size_t i = 0; i < block.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < block.size(); ++j)
        {
            board.getDim(y + i, x + j) -= block.getDim(i, j);
        }
    }
    //Update coordinates
    x = x2;
    y = y2;

    // assign a block with the updated value
    for (size_t i = 0; i < block.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < block.size(); ++j)
        {
            board.getDim(y + i, x + j) += block.getDim(i, j);
        }
    }

    display();
}

void Tetris::collidable()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < stage.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < stage.rowSize(); ++j)
        {
            stage.getDim(i, j) = board.getDim(i, j);
        }
    }
}

bool Tetris::isCollide(int x2, int y2)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < block.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < block.size(); ++j)
        {
            if (block.getDim(i, j) && stage.getDim(y2 + i, x2 + j) != 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void Tetris::userInput()
{
    char key;

    key = _getch();

    switch (key)
    {
    case 'd':
        if (!isCollide(x + 1, y))
        {
            moveBlock(x + 1, y);
        }
        break;
    case 'a':
        if (!isCollide(x - 1, y))
        {
            moveBlock(x - 1, y);
        }
        break;
    case 's':
        if (!isCollide(x, y + 1))
        {
            moveBlock(x, y + 1);
        }
        break;
    case ' ':
        rotateBlock();
    }
}

bool Tetris::rotateBlock()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> tmp(block.size(), std::vector<int>(block.size(), 0));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < tmp.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < tmp.size(); ++j)
        {
            tmp[i][j] = block.getDim(i, j);
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < block.size(); ++i)
    { //Rotate
        for (size_t j = 0; j < block.size(); ++j)
        {
            block.getDim(i, j) = tmp[block.size() - 1 - j][i];
        }
    }

    if (isCollide(x, y))
    { // And stop if it overlaps not be rotated
        for (size_t i = 0; i < block.size(); ++i)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < block.size(); ++j)
            {
                block.getDim(i, j) = tmp[i][j];
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < block.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < block.size(); ++j)
        {
            board.getDim(y + i, x + j) -= tmp[i][j];
            board.getDim(y + i, x + j) += block.getDim(i, j);
        }
    }

    display();

    return false;
}

void Tetris::spawnBlock()
{
    if (!isCollide(x, y + 1))
    {
        moveBlock(x, y + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        collidable();
        makeBlocks();
        display();
    }
}

class Game : public Tetris
{
public:
    Game() = default;
    int menu();
    virtual void gameOverScreen();
    void gameLoop();
    virtual void display();
    void introScreen();

private:
    size_t GAMESPEED = 20000;
};

void Game::gameOverScreen()
{
    COORD coord = { 0, 0 };
    coord.Y++;
    print(" #####     #    #     # ####### ####### #     # ####### ######", coord);
    coord.Y++;
    print("#     #   # #   ##   ## #       #     # #     # #       #     #", coord);
    coord.Y++;
    print("#        #   #  # # # # #       #     # #     # #       #     #", coord);
    coord.Y++;
    print("#  #### #     # #  #  # #####   #     # #     # #####   ######", coord);
    coord.Y++;
    print("#     # ####### #     # #       #     #  #   #  #       #   #", coord);
    coord.Y++;
    print("#     # #     # #     # #       #     #   # #   #       #    #", coord);
    coord.Y++;
    print(" #####  #     # #     # ####### #######    #    ####### #     #", coord);
    coord.Y += 2;
    print("Press any key and enter", coord);
    char a;
    std::cin >> a;
}

void Game::gameLoop()
{
    size_t time = 0;
    initField();

    while (!gameOver)
    {
        if (_kbhit())
        {
            userInput();
        }

        if (time < GAMESPEED)
        {
            time++;
        }
        else
        {
            spawnBlock();
            time = 0;
        }
    }

}

int Game::menu()
{
    introScreen();

    int select_num = 0;

    std::cin >> select_num;

    switch (select_num)
    {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        break;
    default:
        select_num = 0;
        break;
    }

    return select_num;
}

void Game::introScreen()
{
    clearScreen();
    COORD coord = { 0, 0 };
    print("#==============================================================================#", coord);
    coord.Y++;
    print("####### ####### ####### ######    ###    #####", coord);
    coord.Y++;
    print("   #    #          #    #     #    #    #     #", coord);
    coord.Y++;
    print("   #    #          #    #     #    #    #", coord);
    coord.Y++;
    print("   #    #####      #    ######     #     #####", coord);
    coord.Y++;
    print("   #    #          #    #   #      #          #", coord);
    coord.Y++;
    print("   #    #          #    #    #     #    #     #", coord);
    coord.Y++;
    print("   #    #######    #    #     #   ###    #####          made for fun ", coord);
    coord.Y += 4;

    coord.Y++;
    print("     <Menu>", coord);
    coord.Y++;
    print("     1: Start Game", coord);
    coord.Y++;
    print("     2: Quit", coord);

    coord.Y += 2;
    print("#==============================================================================#", coord);
    coord.Y++;
    print("Choose >> ", coord);
    coord.X = strlen("Choose >> ");
    gotoxy(coord.X, coord.Y);
}

void Game::display()
{
    clearScreen();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < board.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < board.rowSize(); ++j)
        {
            switch (board.getDim(i, j))
            {
            case 0:
                std::cout << " " << std::flush;
                break;
            case 9:
                std::cout << "@" << std::flush;
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "#" << std::flush;
                break;
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    COORD coord = { 0, board.size() };

    print("     A: left     S: down     D: right            Rotation[Space]", coord);

    if (gameOver)
    {
        clearScreen();
        gameOverScreen();
    }
}

int main()
{
    Game game;
    switch (game.menu())
    {
        case 1:
            game.gameLoop();
            break;
        case 2:
            return 0;
        case 0:
            COORD coord = { 20, 20 };
            print("Choose 1~2", coord);
            return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: updaded code https://gist.github.com/MORTAL2000/f4701a1f70e7e1e038fc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a few quick comments on things I saw when scanning through:

```
struct Block : public NonCopyable
```

By defining this as a `struct`, you make members `public` (unless overridden).  As a general rule, it is preferred for members to be `private` as a default.  If you are marking a member as `public` then you should have a specific reason for that member.  That pushes you to write code that does not rely on the members being `public`.  You do not seem to be publicly using your `public` members, so you might as well make this a `class`.  Note:  this is not to say that there is never a reason to use a `struct` or `public` member, just that I see no sign of such a reason here.

```
    block.resize(4, std::vector<int>(4, 0));
    field.resize(22, std::vector<int>(13, 0));
    stage.resize(22, std::vector<int>(13, 0));
int x = 4;
Random getRandom{ 0, 6 };
for (size_t i = 0; i <= board.size() - 2; ++i)
    for (size_t j = 0; j <= board.rowSize() - 2; ++j)
        if ((j == 0) || (j == 11) || (i == 20))
            board.getDim(i, j) = stage.getDim(i, j) = 9;
x = 4;
        COORD coord = { 20, 20 };
```

There still seem to be a lot of magic numbers in the code.  Some of them are repeated.

```
Random getRandom{ 0, 6 };
```

could be something like

```
Random getRandom{ 0, blocklist.size() };
```

I don't understand when the following triggers:

```
        if (board.getDim(i, j + block.size()) > 1)
        {
            gameOver = true;
```

It's probably in the code somewhere, but I don't feel like tracking it down now.  A comment of why we are comparing to `1` would be helpful.

Comment: thanks for answer. i agree about `if (board.getDim(i, j + block.size()) > 1)` statement and its double for-loop actually it is not suppose to be in makeBlock function and why comparing to 1 because the `board.getDim` content is all zero. so when it i become 1 due to `block` it means the `board.getDim` get full. its not accurate checking but it's work somehow. i hope i made it clear. it will be clear when i apply deleting complete line if formed

Comment: Don't think I agree with: `As a general rule, it is preferred for members to be private as a default.` **That is too generic a statement**. Sometimes its useful to default to all public; sometimes it is not. Come up with something more specific or get rid of it.

Answer (score 3):

Ok linus only is fine.
But:

```
#ifdef __linux__ 
..... Several pages of stuff.

#else
#error "OS not supported!"
#endif
```

Seems a good way to hide stuff.
Make it all up front.

```
#ifndef __linux__ 
#error "OS not supported!"
#endif

..... Several pages of stuff.
```

OK. We are good programmers and know that static storage duration objects are zero initialized. But not everybody else does.

```
static char init;  // Default initialization of static storage duration
                   // is by zero initialization so this is guaranteed to be zero.

if (init)          // So we know that the first time this is executed.
    return;        // It will fall through and run the following code.
```

But it would be nicer to the less experienced to make this explicit.

```
static char init = 0;

if (init) {
    return;
}
```

Even so this is still is a very C way of doing stuff. A constructor would be nicer.

Prefix underscore is never a good idea.

```
static int _kbhit(void)
```

This is actually a reserved name. Don't use prefix underscore. Even if you know the rules (but you don't) not everybody does. So don't do it even when you do know the rules. See [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/14065). In this case: `Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace`

Platform dependent code:

```
bool gotoxy(unsigned short x = 1, unsigned short y = 1) {
    if ((x == 0) || (y == 0))
        return false;
    std::cout << "\x1B[" << y << ";" << x << "H";
}
```

There are whole libraries that hide terminal dependencies that do this more generically. Look up [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

OK. Just found the.

```
#elif _WIN32
```

So you do have two implementations. In this case it is easier. to do.

```
// Interface declaration here.
... STUFF

#ifdef __linux__ 
#include "<linux File.h>"
#elif _WIN33
#include "<Windowx File.h>"
#else
#error "OS not supported!"
#endif
```

Static three dimensional read only list:

```
static std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> block_list = { /* STUFF */ };
```

Why not an `std::array`. Or just a static **const** C array?

Comment: the original source code was using C array. i did it by `vector` for practicing in C++/C++11. btw cool hat